# How to Draw Mini Bar Charts Inside a Table Cell

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm using matplotlib to create a table visualization. I would like to draw a mini bar chart inside the last cell of each row of the table. The mini bar chart should have two different colors to represent different percentages (for now 50% green and 50% red, gonna handle it later). I would like to show also the percentage of red portion inside the portion with white text.

Here's the Python code to create a reproductible example of what I've so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'B': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'C': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'D': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'BAR': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
})

# Function to draw mini-bar
def draw_mini_bar(ax, x, y, width, height, percentage):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, facecolor='#76ed33'))
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), width * percentage / 100, height, facecolor='#f55d2f'))
    plt.draw()

# Function to render table
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', '#ffffff'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], ax=None, **kwargs):
    
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')
    
    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values, bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    
    for k, cell in mpl_table._cells.items():
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        
        if k[0] == 0:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors)])
        
        # DRAW BARS IN LAST COLUMN
        if k[0] > 0 and k[1] == len(data.columns) - 1:
            draw_mini_bar(ax, cell.get_x(), cell.get_y(), cell.get_width(), cell.get_height(), 50)
            
    plt.show()

render_mpl_table(df)
```

[image]

When I run this code, the mini bar charts don't render as expected. Specifically, they either appear at the wrong positions or the colors don't display correctly.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or know how to draw such mini bar charts inside a matplotlib table cell?

I tried using the add_patch() method to draw rectangles inside table cells. My aim was to create mini bar charts in the last cell of each row. I was expecting the bar to be fully green and a portion of it to be overlaid with red color, representing different percentages (for now I just need to set 50% green and 50% red).

However, the outcome was not as expected. The bars either appeared at the wrong positions or didn't render the colors properly. I can't seem to get the red and green sections to display within the table cells accurately.

Answer (score 1):

#### Notes

Using matplotlib to create custom tables can be quite tricky. In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/table_api.html) for `matplotlib.table` there is even a warning about it!

> The table implementation in Matplotlib is lightly maintained. For a more featureful table implementation, you may wish to try blume.

In a [tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/font_table.html) that is also from the matplotlib documentation there is a note on the different indexing used for tables.

> Beware of table's idiosyncratic indexing...

It would be wise to try a method other than matplotlib for this problem. Regardless, my answer here is based on your code and thus uses matplotlib to address your issue.

#### Final output

This is the figure that the following solution generates. Note the annotated barchart with percentages and proper coloring/positioning.

[image: table with annotated barchart]

#### Solution

Using `ax.add_patch(...)` to manually create the bar chart works fine when the `xy` position coordinates for each cell are set appropriately. `ax.table(...)` automatically sets these coordinates for you, but trying to access them causes indexing issues and messes up the whole table. Instead, use `matplotlib.table.table(...)` to create the table. Then explicitly set the position of each cell before accessing it. This can be done in a single for loop.

#### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.table as mtab # Don't forget this import!
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'B': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'C': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'D': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
    'BAR': np.random.randint(1, 10, 10),
})

# Function to draw mini-bar
def draw_mini_bar(ax, x, y, width, height, percentage):
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), width, height, facecolor='#76ed33', edgecolor='k'))
    ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle((x, y), width* percentage / 100, height, facecolor='#f55d2f', edgecolor='k'))
    # this labels the red bar on each barchart
    ax.text(x+.005, y+(height/2.8), str(percentage)+"%", c='w')
    plt.draw()

# Function to render table
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=2.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', '#ffffff'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], axs=None, **kwargs):
    
    if axs is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        axs.axis('off')
    
    # THIS IS A BIG CHANGE !!! Using matplotlib.table.table instead of ax.table changes everything
    # The cellText param needs to be a 2D list of strings which is why it looks so funky
    mpl_table = mtab.table(ax=axs, cellText=list([[str(j) for j in l] for l in df.values.tolist()]), bbox=bbox, colLabels=data.columns, **kwargs)
    
    # This creates a dictionary of all cells in the table. We can use it to access and manipulate 
    # individual cells. The keys are the row/column indices of each cell
    dictOfCells = mpl_table.get_celld()
    
    # looping through the keys from the dictionary of cells
    for i in dictOfCells.keys():
        cell = dictOfCells[i]
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        
        if i[0] == 0:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[i[0]%len(row_colors)])
            # These are the coordinates for the lower left corner of each cell in the rightmost column
            # THEY NEED TO BE SET EXPLICITLY !!! Change the values as needed for different sized tables
            cell.set(xy=(0.8, (i[0]-1)/11))
            
        # just like above, needs to be set explicitly
        cell.set(height=(1/11))
        # DRAW BARS IN LAST COLUMN
        if i[0]>0 and i[1] == len(data.columns)-1:
            # x and y positions that were set above
            xPos = cell.get_x()
            yPos = cell.get_y()
            # notice that the percentage parameter is set to the value in each cell that the barchart is in
            draw_mini_bar(axs, xPos, yPos, cell.get_width(), cell.get_height(), 10*int(cell.get_text().get_text()))
            
    return mpl_table

# call the function here, can set it equal to a variable for more manipulation of the table
render_mpl_table(df)
plt.show()
```